# Как правильно называется это действие?

Tags: словарь

Подскажите, как правильно, литературно описать действие, когда человек, высовывая язык, издаёт звук "трпр".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В
 зависимости от цели действия, этот человек *гримасничает, 
обезьянничает, юродствует, дразнится, корчит рожу, показывает язык, 
придуряется, шутовствует* и т. п.